# How to find a point with positive integer coordinates which is closest to a line?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, gcd-and-lcm

Given the equation of a line, we need to find a point with positive integer coordinates$^*$ such that the distance of that point from the line is a minimum.

How can we go about it?

$^*$ i.e. both the $x$ and $y$ coordinates are positive integers

Comment: Are the line coefficients integers? In two or three dimensions?

Comment: I believe it is implied that we are working in two dimensions, since OP mentioned $x$ and $y$ coordinates in their post (but not $z$).

Comment: yes the coefficients will be integers.

Comment: yes, we are working in 2 dimensions here.

Answer (score 1):

If the slope is irrational and the line does not go through integer points, you can't.  There will be integer points arbitrarily close to the line.  If the slope is rational, the distances will repeat with period the denominator of the slope.  If the slope is less than $1$ in absolute value, you can look at its inverse by making $x$ a function of $y$ and the repeat will be shorter.

Comment: between what is the 'distance' that is referred here ?

Comment: Normally the distance from a point to a line is perpendicular distance.

Comment: which points are referred here, whose distances with the line is periodic ?

Comment: The closest lattice points. If your line is $y=7x/5 + \sqrt 2$ you can find the closest points with $x=0,1,2,3,4$, compute their distances, and take the closest.  Those distances will repeat in that order, for example the closest distance with $x=5$ will be the same (with the $y$ higher by $7$) than the distance with $x=0$, so you will have found the minimum.

Comment: however if y = (100000001/100000000) *x + 2 , then it would be difficult to find, as in both case we need to see a large number of values.

Comment: Years ago, somebody commented on an answer of mine that search this long finite list doesn't sound very helpful, but compared to search this infinite list it is quite an improvement.  In your example $(100000000,100000003)$ is exactly on the curve.  There may be a way to use continued fractions to guide you, but I haven't found it.